# How can I create layout like this where user clicks on available tags and tag is added to editext?

Tags: android, android-layout

[image]The layout is similar when we add tags to a question on SO.I have tried using various libraries but could not not achieve like above.
https://github.com/kaedea/Android-Cloud-TagView-Plus

Answer (score 0):

This repo may will help you. The screenshot of your question match with this repo's gif.
https://github.com/Cutta/TagView